# Последовательность запуска приложения, написанного на Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

Скачал [исходный код](http://download.transmissionbt.com/files/transmission-2.82.tar.xz) торрент-клиента `Transmission` для изучения. Пытаюсь идти по цепочке, и если я правильно все понял, то:

1. Как и у всех C-подобных программ,
       запуск начинается с функции `main()`
2. Далее, отсюда функция
           `NSApplicationMain()`  запускает
           обработчик (цикл) сообщений, которые
           будут поступать из файлов `.xib`
3. ?
               - и здесь моя цепочка обрывается

В каком месте программа продолжается? Нет нигде ни `AppDelegate`, ни реализации протокола `NSApplicationDelegate`. Не могу уцепиться - выйти из функции `main()` - куда мне последовательно идти? Какой файл дальше просматривать? Файл `.xib` с окном, которое появляется первым при запуске программы, я нашел. Но откуда программа его запускает?

Comment: Посмотрите конфиги проекта, там скорее всего прописан запускающий файл как xib/storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на вопросы в обратном порядке.

Программа запускает файл с окном из main bundle приложения. Это происходит в функции NSApplicationMain. В случае Transmission этот самый .xib - это MainMenu.xib.

Затем стоит просмотреть файл Controller.h. У главного окна приложения через IBOutlet указан экземпляр класса Controller - значит, этот класс будет инстанцирован уже в функции NSApplicationMain. Перед посылкой классу любого другого сообщения будет послано сообщение +initialize, начинать читать можете с него.

После этого будет послан обычный alloc-init, читаете, что происходит в init.

После переходите к awakeFromNib, который вызывается после инициализации объекта, загруженного из nib-файла.

Только после этого NSApplicationMain создаст главный NSRunLoop приложения, который, как вы сказали, будет принимать события от пользовательского интерфейса.